# Ajax подгрузка постов WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте у меня такая проблема, я делаю лендинг на **WordPress**, я создал новую страницу, назвал ее landing-page и сделал статической.

У меня есть портфолио по макету, я создал новый тип записи портфолио, сделал сортировку в виде категорий, затем через `Wp_Query` создал вывод цикла в шаблоне страницы.

И тут смотрите дальше какая проблема, если я не делаю ее статической то получается работает и навигация и некоторые решения с Ajax подгрузкой, все работает с привязкой к url то есть такого вида

> My-site.com/landing-page/page/2
>   My-site.com/landing-page/page/3

А мне же нужно сделать ее главной и получается если я делаю ее статической то **WordPress** пытается переходить по таким url:

> My-site.com/page/2 
>   My-site.com/page/3

Понятное дело что навигация не работает, но и кнопка Ajax подгрузки тоже привязывается к навигации и не работает.

Вот у меня задача как решить проблему с url или не привязывать Ajax к url?

Для Ajax подгрузки использую [это решение](https://truemisha.ru/blog/wordpress/ajax-pagination.html)

Пробовал юзать скрипт `jquery.infinitescroll`, но он тоже привязывается к навигации.

Comment: Что вы вкладываете в понятие "статическая страница"? Кстати пытается переходить по таким ссылкам из-за того, что вы в ссылках не указали схему (протокол)

Comment: Статическая главная страница Word Press на которой выводятся кастомные посты о протоколах не слышал

Comment: Покажите ссылку (элемент <a ...>)

Comment: Какую именно ссылку Вам показать? говорю же я пытался прикрутить ajax подгрузку постов на статическую главную страницу с примера по ссылке но работать оно работает только с привязкой к пагинации. Как я могу обойти эту проблему или как можно подгружать аяксом посты и не привязываться к ссылкам и пагинации?